# Science Fiction novel with women in charge

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading a book when I was young, in the late 60s or early 70s.
The world was ruled by women who lived in a city in the clouds. The planet was occupied solely by the men, who were used as prey for the women to hunt. Reproduction was by parthenogenesis.

Can't remember much of the plot, but I think eventually the women found they needed men for some reason.

I have a feeling this was by one of the well-known authors, but I have looked through the bibliography of Herbert, Heinlein, Silverberg, Pohl, etc. and not found the book yet.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

This might be [Who Needs Men](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1931100.Who_Needs_Men_)? by Edmund Cooper (1972).

> Rura Alexandra, Madam Exterminator, had recently graduated into a 25th century world where men had become biologically less important, where women could reproduce as they wished by cloning and parthenogenesis. Her task was simple - in theory, if not in practice; to wipe out the last few thousand men who had taken refuge in the Highlands of Scotland.

I read it ages ago and remember it as being not very good.  It was also published under the title *Gender Genocide*.